# What are the reasons for process abort, other than memory leak?

Tags: node.js, linux, memory-leaks, process, abort

I have a nodejs application, which is crashing due to process abort. I can see it in /var/log/message. But when monitoring the memory usage, memory usage is stable. Are there any other reasons for memory leak, for which a process can get aborted?

Comment: You would have to do further debugging to diagnose exactly why your process was being aborted.  Is the app crashing?  Is the OS killing it?  There should be some diagnostic message that gives you some clue why it's shutting down.  This isn't supposed to be something you have to guess about.  What EXACTLY do you see in `/var/log/message`?

Comment: stack overflow, memory access errors (segmentation fault), explicit call to [`abort()`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/abort.3.html), `SIGABRT`, ... (Some of the reasons might not apply to a nodejs application, but to C programs only.) Nodejs might call `abort()` as the reaction to a detected error.

Comment: @jfriend00 "Only 1195Mib is available on /var/spool/abrt" and "Process 108588 (node) of user 1003 killed by SIGABRT - ignoring (low free space)" . This is what I am getting in /var/log/messages. Any idea why this might be happening?

Comment: I don't know what that message means.  Please add that precise message to your question (using the "edit" link and maybe someone else who can help will see it.